# How to read the current frame buffer in android?

Tags: android, framebuffer

Is there a method to read the frame buffer of the current screen? I searched some data about the frame buffer. Some one used the glReadPixels method, but the information was not enough. Does anyone know how to read the current frame buffer in detail?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4):

Do you actually want the *screen* framebuffer? Or some OpenGL surface that your app has created?

If the former, see
[How to capture the android device screen content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content)

If the latter, you are on the right track with `glReadPixels`.

Answer (score 0):

in cmd line

1. `adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/abc.png`
2. `adb pull /sdcard/abc.png`
3. find your screen capture png file in your adb directory.

Edit according to  Chris Stratton :

**If you gonna implement this cmd in Java code, root permission is needed**

thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: No, root permission is **not** needed **to do what you have shown here**.  adb provides the necessary permission to use those particular tools - that's how the DDMS screenshot button works. However, **you cannot use those tools from code on device without some sort of hack**, as adb only listens on the USB connection by default.