# capture Desktop Image

Tags: java, image, desktop

I want to capture a Desktop image through Coding most probably in Java?? How to achieved it ??

Comment: Windows os,I m having windows Vista....!!!!

Comment: Since he's talking about android, possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content

Comment: nope it was abt capturing the Android Content,I dont want this !!!!

Answer (score 3):

See the `java.awt.Robot` class.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)

Once you have a reference to the `BufferedImage` object, you can use the `ImageIO` class to write to a file.

Comment: Ok,How to capture desktop image On Android Emulator ?? Because Android does not support AWT classes