# how to take snapshot of screen programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to take screenshot of screen programatically.I also downloaded android-screenshot-library, but i am not understanding how to use it. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the [Usage page](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/Usage)?

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take screenshot programmatically of the whole screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748384/take-screenshot-programmatically-of-the-whole-screen)

Answer (score 4):

Follow this guide: [Developer guide for android-screenshot-library](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/DeveloperGuide).

Also read this: [How to capture the android device screen content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content)  may be become helpful to you.

Comment: Is there any other way to capture screen without ASL becoz i do not want to start service

Comment: @user437833: AFAIK no there is not.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged since either (A) the links can break or (B) the question is effectively a dupe and should be closed.