# Taking Screenshot using native android API

Tags: android, api, screenshot, native

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to take snapshot of screen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973974/how-to-take-snapshot-of-screen-programmatically)

As part of building my new app, I would like to allow the user to take a screenshot of the device using a button in my app.
However I need this done without rooting of the device, using native API.

I was trying to look for references and android developer site, but couldn't find the native API functionality to do the above.

Can you please confirm that it is indeed possible to do the above (Taking a screenshot programmatically)?
Can you please also direct me to somewhere I can see the API at?

Comment: Do you want to take the screenshot of your application?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class ScreenShotActivity extends Activity {

    Bitmap bmScreen;
    RelativeLayout mLayout;
    Dialog screenDialog;
    static final int ID_SCREENDIALOG = 1;

    ImageView bmImage;
    Button btnScreenDialog_OK;
    // TextView TextOut;

    View screen;
    EditText EditTextIn;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        screen = (View) findViewById(R.id.screen);
        Button btnCaptureScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capturescreen);

        btnCaptureScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                bmScreen = screen.getDrawingCache();
                saveImage(bmScreen);
                // showDialog(ID_SCREENDIALOG);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void saveImage(Bitmap bmScreen2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // String fname = "Upload.png";
        File saved_image_file = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/captured_Bitmap.png");
        if (saved_image_file.exists())
            saved_image_file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(saved_image_file);
            bmScreen2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Add permission too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

XML for this will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/capturescreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Capture Screen" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/android_awesome" />

</RelativeLayout>
```