# Programmatically scroll an Android app using another app running in the background?

Tags: android, iphone

I am creating an Android app and I am also planning and an iPhone version, so I am looking for the opinions of both Android and iPhone developers. The app I am creating runs in the background, i.e. it has no GUI, and checks if another app is running.

If the other app is running I want to take screenshots using my background app, every few seconds.

- **Is taking screenshots with an app running in the background possible?**
- **I also want to scroll the screen of the foreground app programmatically using my background app, is this possible?**

Comment: What have you tried? What did you look at so far? This is not a consulting service :)

Comment: As far as I know, Android apps are suspended when not foreground, and they cannot perform any tasks.
However, android services can.

Comment: @LordT I have not tried anything yet because I am extremely busy with developing the server that will be servicing these apps. This is a very uncommon use case so it is tough to find information, that's why I am hoping some experienced Android/iPhone devs will have some information. Just like the last question you asked was about what was possible regarding an iPhone scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On both OSes, it's not possible to take screenshots while in the background without being root.
On Android there are several services that already take screenshots - and all of these run as root - check these: [how to take snapshot of screen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973974/how-to-take-snapshot-of-screen-programmatically)
On iOS, it's only possible via private API.

Scrolling programatically is possible acting as a keyboard type app (on android at least). Check out a keyboard example or other accessabilty apps. That's the way I could see that might work.

Comment: Damn, looks like Google have Android locked down hard...I'm going to have to look into other methods for what I need to do as I don't think I can ask end users to root their phones.