# Android recording Video

Tags: android, video, video-recording

is it generally possible to recording videos with an additional layer which is also recording?

If yes,how can I do that?

Maybe with 
`android.view.Surface`?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
[MediaRecorder API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

Comment: Thx for your reply, but I´ve seen this already. I see no methode or so to realize e.g. watermarking.

Comment: Sorry, got your question wrong. What you're looking for is recording both video from the camera and the overlay, right? If you know to overlay the video, try checking this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content

Comment: Yes exactly. So, if there is no other solution I have to try it ;)