# set chmod permission in Android

Tags: android

I want to set permission on a file of sdcard that no one can delete the same, for this I want to run chmod 400 command on that file, but I don't know how to do that programmatically in android. Please suggest me any solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use caution with this approach. The SD card generally uses a FAT filesystem without per-user permissions. Even if you were able to do a `chmod 400` (which you may be able to do with the `Runtime.exec()`, or [File.setReadOnly()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setReadOnly%28%29) method or similar), it may not be a good idea to do it directly on the SD card filesystem, because nothing prevents someone from simply marking it read/write again.

You should use the official [data storage APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), which should be sufficient for your needs. (and more secure assuming a non-rooted device)

Comment: Hi Mike.. can you tell me how to use chmod command in android programmatically? I am trying to give Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /dev/ttyS0") but it is not working eventhough I have the root permissions for ttyS0..

Comment: @SivaKumar, on my Android device, `chmod` is a symbolic link to `/system/bin/toolbox`. But I don't think that's the issue. From Java code, in order to execute commands as root, you will need to be authorized through the `su` binary. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882248/running-shell-commands-though-java-code-on-android) for details.

Comment: First part is just wrong. There is no hard rule on the filesystem type on Android. But yes I wouldn't use `chmod` usually on Android either way.

Comment: Updated the answer slightly to clarify. When I wrote this answer ~11 years ago, I worked with a wide variety of major Android devices, and none of them coped well with non-FAT formatted SD cards. While this may have changed, I feel like removable SD cards have also fallen out of fashion.