# Run adb shell command using android code

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-notifications, led

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness
```

The above command is working perfectly through adb shell.But when I try to run through my code there is no effect.Here is my code.

```
Process mSuProcess;
mSuProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 
DataOutputStream mSuDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mSuProcess.getOutputStream()); 
mSuDataOutputStream.writeBytes("echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness \n");
mSuDataOutputStream.flush();
mSuDataOutputStream.close();
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Although you say you are 'rooted' that does not necessarily mean you have an `su` binary usable for this purpose.  See if you can manage to capture the stdout /stderr of the su process.  Also consider installing something like connectbot and trying your commands in an interactive shell on the device, which will run as an application userid and thus give you a more comparable case than adb does.

Answer (score 2):

If the device which you are working on is not rooted then this may not work..

Comment: Run shell instead of su, like;

Process mSuProcess;  mSuProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh");

Comment: try this one please mSuProcess.getOutputStream().writeBytes("echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness \n");  and keep it through "su"

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882248/running-shell-commands-though-java-code-on-android).. hopefully will help you

Comment: Your code should work.. i dont see any reason why this is happening.. best luck

Answer (score 1):

The google original `su` binary checks for `UID` and only works if run by `root` or `shell` users. This is why it works when you run your command from adb shell interactively. In order to run this code from a java app you need to use a patched `su` binary - without `UID` checks.