# How to execute UIAutomator test case from own developed android App?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I have a uiautomator test project jar which automate camera and camcoder app. i can execute it from the pc shell command. But can't execute it from APK.

Any solutions...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

An app cannot run a `uiautomator` test case, except perhaps on a rooted device, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: @ashish: I have not attempted to run any commands as root. I would assume that you do it however everyone else runs commands as root. At least a few years ago, you would use something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6882295/115145 But I have no idea if that is the approach that you would use today.