# Connect to wifi access point using Appium

Tags: appium

I work for a company who provides wifi. I have some access point setup and I would like to write some automated tests that simulate the connecting to these access points.

So my test would be something like this:

1. Launch Device
2. Go to wifi settings on device
3. Select wifi you wish to connect to
4. Verify that the device is able to successfully connect to wifi. (When testing this manually on IOS, our splash page automatically pops up, on Android I generally need to open a browser and then the splash page is displayed)

Is it be possible to use Appium to do this? If so I would really appreciate if someone could provide some more information on how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you find find something useful at the following link : http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6694/appium-vs-androiddriver-iphonedriver-in-mobile-automation-tests

Comment: Sadly at present, you'll have better luck doing this with non-mobile device for automation such as Windows, Linux, or Mac. Android is best bet for mobile side, good luck trying to do that for iOS, and perhaps Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire ADB Command to turn your Wifi On like this
adb -s $PHONESERIAL shell "svc wifi enable"

You can include/fire such command using Appium by including it within your test case (Java Code) [Use this to know how to fire ADB Commands problematically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882248/running-shell-commands-though-java-code-on-android)

Comment: and sadly that's only for Android :(