# Run linux command in android

Tags: android, linux, usb, connectivity

I have requirement of resetting usb device(example - Internet dongle connectivity is lost and then without plug-out/plug-in the connectivity should happen)

I have found following command that fulfills above requirement in linux(ubuntu)

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x140b --reset-usb
```

where 0x12d1 and 0x140b are usb device related id's.

How can I perform above command in android code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6882295