# java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied) on a rooted device

Tags: android, sockets, android-networking

The following code throws "java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" on a rooted tablet:

```
 DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(67);
```

I thought binding to privileged port 67 was allowed on a rooted device.  Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a device is "rooted", that does not give permission to arbitrary apps to do anything they want with root privileges.  Rooted devices merely allow arbitrary apps to request to use the `su` command line to execute new processes with root privileges via a command line.

[See this, for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882248/running-shell-commands-though-java-code-on-android)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer.  I am using  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c ifconfig eth0 up") in the code.  Does it help invoke the privilege?

Comment: No, your main app process will never be able to do things with root privileges.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Do you happen to know a way to get around this?

Comment: If I knew a workaround, I would not have said "never" in the above comment.

Comment: Could you do me one more favor: is it possible to compile to custom ROM to allow apps to have root privileges?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about that.