# How to take screenshot programmatically on Android?

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to take a fullscreen screenshot programmatically ,
for example, one of the android home screen or a menu.
How can I get a view of the home screen in my application?
***I want to take it programmatically!!!***
It doesn't matter if it requires root mode!

Help me please and sorry for my English!

Comment: > Did you try
> [this](http://www.androidcentral.com/taking-screenshots-without-root)
> ? Or in french you can [read
> that](http://www.actualitemobile.com/forum/index.php?topic=9490.0) EDIT : So if you want to programm that, you may following these links : - a [command line solution](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=168) (usable in Java)
- you may get somes informations [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/tools/screenshot/src/com/android/screenshot/Screenshot.java)

Comment: Oh snap! Just realized (after posting my answer of course -_-): Do you mean from an android application?

Comment: I want to take it programmaticaly!!!

Comment: Yes, I did! But I want to take it programmatically!!!

Comment: Ok, you may say that on your question

Comment: What about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android

Answer (score 13):

Use following code

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = MyView.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Here MyView is the View through which we need include in screen.

Comment: This just take screenshot of active application only. Not entire android screen.

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh .. please take a look..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content/8504958#8504958 ..... this may help you...

Answer (score 5):

Follow the link 
https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/downloads/list
 it allows you entire screenshot of any screen not only your app

adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/img.png
this is a shell command take screenshot simple and fast

Try this

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
   OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
   os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            sh.waitFor();
```

Comment: I have 2 devices (Android v2.2 & v2.3.3) which have no `screencap` file in `/system/bin` directory. So it doesn't suit me.

Comment: @ares u can try the above link.

Comment: would u more describe cz i tried but i'm not getting the result ?

Comment: @user2078315 which version of android u r running, make sure inside /system/bin a file named screencap file exist , then run the above code in program it should work

Answer (score 0):

In the  adb shell you can use command as

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
adb pull /sdcard/screen.png
adb shell rm /sdcard/screen.png
```

I found this code on this guide on [How to take a screenshot on Android](http://howtotakescreenshot.net/on-android/).You can refer it for more details.Hope this helps.