# Android - Capture ScreenShot Programmatically without title bar

Tags: android

I am developing an app in that I want to take a screen shot of current screen but with out title bar. I know the code to Capture a ScreenShot, but unable to customize it.

Code:

```
munchscreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View v1 = L1.getRootView();
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.screenshots);
                image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
            }
        });
```

When I click on `Clip` then it should capture a screen shot of the screen shown below but should not include the part which I have circled..

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#D8D5AA"
>


  <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/clip_from_web_linearlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:orientation="horizontal"             
    >
         <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/clip_from_web_textview_back"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        /> 

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/clip_from_web_textview_header_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clip From Web"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        /> 

      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/clip_from_web_textview_clip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        /> 

    </LinearLayout>


          <Button
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/munch"
             android:id="@+id/munchscreen"
             android:layout_below="@+id/clip_from_web_linearlayout1"
           />
           <ImageView
             android:layout_width="200dp"
             android:layout_height="200dp"
             android:id="@+id/screenshots"
             android:layout_below="@+id/munchscreen"
             android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"

             />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/clip_from_web_bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/header" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/clip_from_web_previous"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/clip_from_web_reload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/clip_from_web_next"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clip_from_web_reload"
        android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Image before Capturing screen shot..

[image]

Image after Capturing screen shot..

[image]

Comment: follow http://www.truiton.com/2013/03/android-take-screenshot-programmatically-and-send-email/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514325/how-to-take-screenshot-programmatically

Comment: @Piyush Gupta I can't post my xml. But, I am trying it on demo program so I will post the xml of that program..

Comment: are you using web view anywhere?

Comment: @Piyush Gupta: Please check my updated question. I have posted whole XML and proper screen shot

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay:: Not working.. Please check my updated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take this to another Linear Layout

```
  <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">       

       <Button
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/munch"
         android:id="@+id/munchscreen"

       />
       <ImageView
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="200dp"
         android:id="@+id/screenshots"
         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
         />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Now find Id for this Linear Layout on oncreate() method making it global variable

```
 LinearLayout ll;

 ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
```

now capture this screen

```
 ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 ll.buildDrawingCache(true);
 Bitmap cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(ll.getDrawingCache());
 ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Now set this bitmap to your ImageView.

Comment: What is rel? .. Last line

Comment: Please edit your code as `ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` .. You have written false. If I do so then it displays black image. When I make it to true then it works perfect.. :)

Comment: Just see proper at first line i wrote it..Because its trying to prepare for it and after that capture the screen it should be false..So no need to change

Comment: Ok. Fine. But, I told you the things which I encountered. It is working for me when I make it to true. Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
    munchscreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View contentView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            contentView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            contentView.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap drawingCache = contentView.getDrawingCache();
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), drawingCache);
            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.screenshots);
            image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey friends I got the solution of above problem.

Follow below steps:-

1. activity_main.xml

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/toolbar_rl"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
       android:background="@color/header_color"
       android:visibility="visible">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:weightSum="0"
           tools:ignore="UselessParent">

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
               android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_back_24" />

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
               android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:text="@string/one_time"
               android:textColor="@color/white"
               android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
               tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />


           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
               android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_icon" />


       </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

   <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/tabScroll"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fillViewport="true">

       <TableLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:stretchColumns="1">

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="210dp"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:background="@drawable/otp_background"
               android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
               android:scaleType="fitXY">

           </ImageView>

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
               android:background="#fff"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:text="Enter Unique Identification Number"
               android:textColor="@color/header_color"
               android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp" />

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/layout_otp"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_26sdp"
               android:gravity="top|center"
               android:orientation="horizontal">

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/editTextone"
                   android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/_42sdp"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:maxLength="1"
                   android:nextFocusRight="@+id/editText_two"
                   tools:ignore="LabelFor">

                   <requestFocus />
               </EditText>

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/editTexttwo"
                   android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/_42sdp"
                   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                   android:maxLength="1"
                   tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/editTextthree"
                   android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/_42sdp"
                   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                   android:maxLength="1"
                   tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/editTextfour"
                   android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/_42sdp"
                   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                   android:maxLength="1"
                   tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/editTextfive"
                   android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/_42sdp"
                   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                   android:maxLength="1"
                   tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

           </LinearLayout>


           <Button
               android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
               android:layout_width="@dimen/_220sdp"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_46sdp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_16sdp"
               android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_26sdp"
               android:background="@drawable/editbox_one"
               android:text="@string/capture"
               android:textAllCaps="false"
               android:textColor="#fff"
               android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
               android:typeface="serif" />
       </TableLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   ```

   2. This xml looks like.

[image]

3. in MainActivity Add some code.

   3.1 Declare the Button.

   ```
     Button button_submit;
   ```

   3.2 Initialize the button.

   ```
    button_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
   ```

   3.3 Set set OnClickListener to this button and Call one method i.e

   ```
    takeScreenshot();
   ```

   Note:- When you click on this button that time automatically  capture the screen without title bar and it will store in file explore with current date, time and.jpg extension(Ex. Fri May 11 151938 GMT+0530 2018.jpg) and this captured image as a bitmap if you want you can set this bitmap to ImageView .
4. The Code of takeScreenshot().

   ```
    private void takeScreenshot() {

    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

   try {

   String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

   View u = findViewById(R.id.tabScroll);
   u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   ScrollView z = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.tabScroll);
   z.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
   int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
   int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
   u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
   u.buildDrawingCache(true);
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
   u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

   File imageFile = new File(mPath);

   FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
   int quality = 100;
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
   outputStream.flush();
   outputStream.close();

    } catch (Throwable e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ```
5. The output be looks like..

[image]

I hope it will helpful for you.