# Take a screeshot of the screen via android phone

Tags: android

how can I screen capture via android.I mean I want to write a program which make a screenshot of the screen.any link appreciated ,thank you all

Comment: Of your app or of any app?

Comment: what??can u give me details

Comment: Do you want to take a screenshot of your own app, or of any app?

Comment: any app running on the phone

Comment: thank you parmar,yea it seems dublicated

Comment: Simply, you can't! You can only shoot your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code to take a screenshot of **MY APP (you can't take a picture of other apps)**:

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
protected final static boolean shoot
(final View v, final String appName)
{
    // Get the bitmap from the view
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    boolean isOK = false;

    final Bitmap bmp = v.getDrawingCache();

    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd@HHmmss");
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Set file properties
    fileJPG = appName + "_" + sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    /*
    Create a path where we will place our picture in the user's public
    pictures directory. Note that you should be careful about what you
    place here, since the user often manages these files.
    For pictures and other media owned by the application, consider
    Context.getExternalMediaDir().
    */
    final File path =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
        (
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Your_App_Name/"
        );

    // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
    if(!path.exists())
    {
        path.mkdirs();
    }

    final File file = new File(path, fileJPG + ".jpg");

    try
    {
        final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        final BufferedOutputStream bos =
            new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 8192);

        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, bos);

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

        fileJPG = file.getPath();
        isOK = true;
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isOK;
}
```

Comment: I just downloaded a programe whick take a screenshot of any app.how that possiable

Comment: easy screeshot of the name of app on the android market

Comment: Is you phone **ROOTED**?

Comment: noo It is not  rooted

Comment: So, it's very strange, since you normally don't have the permissions to do that. See FD_'s answer for details

Comment: I just press power button and voice down buttun at the same time and get the screen shot of any app.I also no rooted ,I am confused

Comment: See if [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15186761/2649012) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15208592/2649012) will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible as easily as you'd like it to. There is no official API for that for security reasons.

Here are your options:

- Using the screencap command line tool: Needs root permission, not installed on all phones
- Getting the frame buffer: Requires root
- Using [android-screenshot-library](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/): Requires adb connection for start