# Saving an image of the screen using jQuery and Phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, cordova

I'm building an Android mobile application using HTML, CSS and JavaScript (jQuery) which will be compiled using Phonegap.

Is there any way to take a screenshot of everything on the screen at that moment and store it on your phone?

Many thanks

Comment: This can't be done with HTML, CSS, or JS. So it would have to be achieved by something that Phonegap offers, or by directly communicating with the Android OS

Comment: Yes, This cannot be done by these technologies.. You may have to use android API to achieve this. Here is the post discussing the same..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved this by creating my own plugin for PhoneGap.

https://github.com/jcrowson/Android-Phonegap-Screenshot-Plugin

It uses Android native Java code to capture the WebView.

Comment: how to capture particular content only

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are asking for, but it might help:

Using an app like ScreenShotUX (which I have used minus paying) from [here](http://www.appbrain.com/app/screenshot-ux/com.liveov.shotux), the user can merely shake the phone while in your app, and the app can fetch the screenshot from a defualt location like `/mnt/sdcard/ScreenCapture/`

With the screen shot taken for you, you can then use PhoneGap and javascript to read it, and probably even send it to a server.  (see [this plugin here](http://www.toforge.com/2011/02/phonegap-android-plugin-for-download-files-from-url-on-sd-card/) for using phonegap to read form sdcard)

Might be easier than what you are asking for.