# How to convert an activity into an image

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with some views, after doing some stuff I want to convert the look of this activity into an image and email it. I can mail an image, but how can i make that activity into an image? Is it possible?

Comment: Try SO - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could programatically take a screenshot of your device, that should do the trick. Take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/782719), it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can render different views of your app to `Bitmap` Objects, by capturing the `drawing cache`.

just refer to http://blog.neurolive.net/2010/11/385/ for more details. (thx, for the great tutorial)

especially

```
private Bitmap getScreenViewBitmap(View v) {
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    // this is the important code :)  
    // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null          
    v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight()); 

    v.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
}
```

seems what you would be interested in. (Just find your top-level View and use this method to capture the Bitmap)