# Capture Android screenshot without having the View

Tags: java, android

I have found a lot of examples like this:

[how to Capture screen in android and covert it to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360664/how-to-capture-screen-in-android-and-covert-it-to-image)

I need to capture an screenshot of screen activity, but I'm developing an external library, so I can't get current activity of the application to get the View and then flush the bitmap into canvas. Is there another way to capture a screenshot?

Comment: "I'm developing an external library, so I can't get current activity of the application" -- when the app using the library wants a screenshot, have it pass in the `View`, or the `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to save the image from Snapchat, you need to save the Bitmap in another way.
With a rooted phone you can access the apps storage and copy the image while the app shows it.
That way the app wont notice you took a "Screenshot" :)