# Application screen print

Tags: android

I have come across 3rd party softwares that help in printing from an android device like GoogleCloudPrint and PrinterShare. This would print the docs or images present on the device. What I want is to print the application screen itself, in the sense for example a screen having a list view within my app. I want to print the screen having the list view. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of how good you want it. For example it would be fairly easy to just take a snapshot of the screen and then print it. Have a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/DeveloperGuide)  and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content)

But if you want something better then I guess you will have to format it yourself.