# How to use ScreenShotClient in my android application

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, screenshot

I am developing an application which helps user to capture android screen shot (Android 4.x) . I know that framebuffer is broken on android ICS. I hear that we can use ScreenShotClient to do this as below.

```
ScreenshotClient screenshotClient = new ScreenshotClient();
screenshotClient->update();
```

But, what library I have to import to use it? Is it available to use under jni code?

Comment: Isn't this duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android?

Comment: No. the answers at that question didn't help.

Comment: OK, have you seen the answer in [**how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content#7979151)?

Comment: Yes, I did. I wrote a similar app which using ScreenShotClient to take screenshot, but I couldn't build it. The needed library was not found.

Comment: Have you found the **surfaceflinger_client/SurfaceComposerClient.h** file?

Comment: I downloaded that file (and many other needed files) from https://github.com/android then put them into /jni folder but I can't build it. My JNI folder was shared here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15261504/jni.zip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The library you need is called **libsurfaceflinger_client.so**. You can pull it from any device running Gingerbread <strike>or higher</strike> version of Android, with command

```
adb pull /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger_client.so
```

On ICS or JB, class **ScreenshotClient** is part of `libgui.so`. The makefile for screencap which is the example of using **ScreenshotClient**, suggests that linker may need other libraries:

```
libcutils libutils libbinder libskia libui libgui
```

Also, the code of `screencap.cpp` goes as follows:

```
ScreenshotClient screenshot;
if (screenshot.update() == NO_ERROR) {
    base = screenshot.getPixels();
    w = screenshot.getWidth();
    h = screenshot.getHeight();
    f = screenshot.getFormat();
    size = screenshot.getSize();
} else {
    const char* fbpath = "/dev/graphics/fb0";
    int fb = open(fbpath, O_RDONLY);
    if (fb >= 0) {
        struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
        if (ioctl(fb, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) == 0) {
...
```

This means that at least you must check that update() succeed. Unfortunately, unless teh device is rooted, the apps cannot be granted permission to read from `/dev/graphics/fb0` and use the fallback of `/system/bin/screencap` or `/system/bin/screenshot`.

Comment: Yeah. I can pull it from that folder to my Project. But I don't know how to use it to capture android screen. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Wait a sec. You wrote elsewhere that you have the code in your project, but cannot build it because you don't know where to find the **.so** file

Comment: Hm. The adb command does not work for my device running Android 4.1.1.: **remote object '/system/lib/libsurfaceflinger_client.so' does not exist**

Comment: Well, on 4.0 and higher the library is called **libgui.so**. The makefile for `screencap` which is ***the*** example of using **ScreenshotClient**, suggests that linker may need other libraries: `libcutils libutils libbinder libskia libui libgui`.