# How get fast pixel color on Android use ScreenshotClient?

Tags: android, gcc, arm, screen-capture, native-code

I want get color pixel use an binary file with params x and y. The screencap is very slow. Using a virtual display also does not give the desired result.

I found and  code [screencap](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp), and good project: [sji-android-screen-capture-old](https://github.com/sankaryg/sji-android-screen-capture) and [sji-android-screen-capture-new](https://github.com/sjitech/sji-android-screen-capture).

But those solutions don't run in my phone. If run get-raw-image.cpp after compile [get-raw-image.cpp](https://github.com/sankaryg/sji-android-screen-capture/blob/master/src/get-raw-image.cpp) I get errors:

```
WARNING: linker: /data/local/tmp/get-raw-image-4.1.2: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x21d
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android16ScreenshotClient6updateERKNS_2spINS_7IBinderEEE".
```

For compilation, I use the following settings:

```
/root/arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang -pie get-raw-image.cpp -lsupc++ libgui.so -o /get-raw-image-4.1.2 -Xlinker -rpath=/system/lib -DTARGET_JB
```

If run [Android-fast-screen-capture](https://github.com/ClnViewer/Android-fast-screen-capture):

```
/root/arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang -pie /screen/ascreencap.cpp -o /test -std=c++11
```

I had errors:

```
In file included from /screen/ascreencap.cpp:8:
In file included from /root/arm/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/binder/IPCThreadState.h:21:
/root/arm/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/binder/Parcel.h:86:11: error: unknown type
      name 'binder_size_t'
    const binder_size_t* objects() const;
          ^
/root/arm/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/binder/Parcel.h:220:47: error: unknown type
      name 'binder_size_t'
                                        const binder_size_t* objects, si...
                                              ^
/root/arm/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/binder/Parcel.h:228:51: error: unknown type
      name 'binder_size_t'
                                            const binder_size_t* objects...
                                                  ^
/root/arm/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/binder/Parcel.h:264:5: error: unknown type
      name 'binder_size_t'
    binder_size_t*      mObjects;
    ^
In file included from /screen/ascreencap.cpp:8:
/root/arm/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/binder/IPCThreadState.h:114:50: error:
      unknown type name 'binder_size_t'
                                           const binder_size_t* objects...
                                                 ^
5 errors generated.
```

Also I found the question [how-to-use-screenshotclient-in-my-android-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560957/how-to-use-screenshotclient-in-my-android-application) but I don't understand how set link to ScreenshotClient, so that the compiler does not return an error.

My phone is Homtom HT16:

```
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 26.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
```

Maybe someone will tell you how to compile the code under my phone or which way to go to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

Steps:

1) Copy need library from android phone (`libgui.so, libui.so, libcutils.so, libutils.so, libbinder.so`).

2) Add in sys_root (when save ndk lib code files from Android [Android 6_r1](https://github.com/xdtianyu/android-6.0.0_r1) libs: `utils, cutils, system, log, hardware, system, ports, core, include/gui, include/ui, include/binder`). You can run this code for find your system root:

```
echo "#include &lt;bogus.h&gt; int main(){}" > t.c; GCC_OR_CLANG_BINARY_LINK -v t.c; rm t.c
```

Erors printed all paths where compiler search include files.
or use `--sysroot=YOUR_PATH` for set your path.

3) Add flags `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all` for ignore errors and `--target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi23` (23 or other) for set target version.

Full my clang command:

```
/Users/macbookair/Documents/test/bin/clang -fPIE -pie fast-screen-capture.cpp *.so -o ./screencap --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi23 -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all -s
```

Successes!