# How to take snapshot of device screen programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to  take snapshot of my device screen's snapshot on Button click. Please provide some code sample instead of links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can take screenshot of your app only, otherwise that would be a security breach in android

Comment: yes i want to take screenshot of my own app.

Comment: Check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content  http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/DeveloperGuide

Comment: If you need screenshot for outside you app you can use android-screenshot-library:
[http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/)

Comment: @DeepikaLalra we want snapshot when button click....

Comment: yes nagarjunaReddy make the answer below on button click...

Comment: what about out of app ? Is this possible to take a snapshot out of the app ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer for my question. Actualy i am getting bitmap as null. but i found the reason and the solution.

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.attachments_list);
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    // this is the important code :)
    // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will
    // be null
    v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

    v.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
```

Comment: no not yet. Actually i read somewhere that every site has its own mechanism to provide thumbnails like youtube provided. but there is not an hard and fast rule to get thumb for video Url. Another thing is we can make thumbnail for a video which is saved in phone or dowloaded but for streaming videos there is no specific way.

Comment: http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?url=PASTE YOUR URL&maxwidth=500

Comment: @venkat you make a function which can call this url and get the json an parse that json and you can get all information about that video. I did using this url and this works like a charm.

Comment: @Venkat do not append http:// with url. try using www. as a prefix for your URl. it will work already tested by me.

Comment: thank you... after remove http://from the url its working fine...

Comment: @DeepikaLalra but i want take the screen shot of another activity ..

Answer (score 1):

You can't take your Device's screenshot(not rooted) but within your application you can.

Below is the code which takes screenshot of your application's screen and save a file in your sdcard.

```
mLayoutRoot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); //mLayoutRoot is your Parent Layout(may be RelativeLayout, LinearLayout or etc..)
mLayoutRoot.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap mBitmap= mLayoutRoot.getDrawingCache();
try {
    if(mBitmap!=null)
    {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/filename.png"));
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: getting mLayoutRoot.getDrawingCache() as null :(

Comment: have you initialized `mLayoutRoot` with findViewById(R.id.parentid);? *Check again*