# Share live screen on android device

Tags: android

i got an issue.
I'd like to develop an application to share my android screen to another android screen, so what i do on my android screen will show the same on another screen.

How can i do this? Do you know any research or API to support this one.

Thanks for any comments

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content

Comment: No, that's link present android screen shot, not my intent. My intent is share live android screen, so what i did on my device, the shared device will see instantly.