# how to get the content of mobile screen that can share to other mobile?

Tags: android

Hello friends i want to share my phone screen with other android phone. But i don't understand ho to get the current content of screen. One method is to take snap shot and send it. I don't want it because other mobile phone also able to give command. Any code snap or link that will help me. And how about Display Manager and google cast API ?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content

Comment: No i don't want to get the screen shot of my mobile and send over the network i also mention that.